# UIActivityViewController local Image

Tags: ios, imageview, uiactivityviewcontroller

How do i share image from imageView. Here is my code for imageView:

```
    UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:
                                            @"image%d.jpg", i]];
    UIImageView *myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:myImage];

    [myImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(xOrigin, 0,
                                     self.view.frame.size.width,
                                     self.view.frame.size.height)];

    _postImage.image = myImage;
}

- (IBAction)shareButtonPressed:(id)sender {
NSArray *activityItems;

if (_postImage.image != nil) {
  activityItems = @[_postImage.image];
                    }

 UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc]       
 initWithActivityItems:activityItems                                                                             
  applicationActivities:nil];
  [self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];
 }
```

I get error - No share action available.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that your activityItems array is not nil. I mean are you able to access the _postImage.image? first please find these things using break point or nslog then let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot to initialize `_postImage`. Try to replace:

```
_postImage.image = myImage;
```

with:

```
_postImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:myImage];
```

Answer (score 0):

To get your image on activityViewController you need to create your custom Activity with that image which you want to show. Following are step's to create and show your custom activity with your image.

1.Create a new file subclassing UIActivity namely, "CustomActivity". Then in the CustomActivity.m file you need to write down following method.

```
- (NSString *)activityType {
 return @"yourappname.Review.App";  //type
}

- (NSString *)activityTitle {
return @"Review App";     //title for activity
}

- (UIImage *)activityImage {
    return [UIImage imageNamed:@"Icon.png"];  //image
}

- (BOOL)canPerformWithActivityItems:(NSArray *)activityItems {
  NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
  return YES;
 }

- (void)prepareWithActivityItems:(NSArray *)activityItems {
  NSLog(@"%s",__FUNCTION__);
}

- (UIViewController *)activityViewController {
  NSLog(@"%s",__FUNCTION__);
  return nil;
 }

- (void)performActivity {
//What your cust activity woudl perform when user tap onto it.
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.apple.com/"]];

  [self activityDidFinish:YES];
 }
```

Then in your mainVC you could import this class and add below lines to use this custom activity.

```
NSString *textItem = @"provide your string";
UIImage *imageToShare = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Icon.png"];  //Provide your activity image

NSArray *items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:textItem,imageToShare,nil];

custAct = [[CustomActivity alloc]init];

UIActivityViewController *controller =  [[UIActivityViewController alloc]  initWithActivityItems:items   applicationActivities:@[custAct]];
[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Now you would be able to see your image with activity that you want to perform.
If my understanding is wrong, do correct me.